# Will 3D wing has smaller drag than 2D at same AoA and airflow speed?

Tags: aerodynamics

We meassure lift and drag for 2D and 3D wing case,we use same airfoil at same AoA and same airflow speed for both case.
Wind tunnel can change test section walls width.

2D wing test:

So first we put airfoil in wind tunnel so walls touch arifoil tips(2D wing),at AoA=15degrees and airflow speed=20m/s  and meassure lift and drag..

3D wing test:

Now we increase walls width so airflow "act" like 3D wing in test section.We use same AoA=15 and same airflow speed (20m/s) over airfoil like in 2D wing- test.
note: AoA=15 is angle between chord line and freestream airflow not angle between chord line and effective airflow at 3D wing

Question is,what will be drag of 3D wing-test compare to 2D wing-test,smaller ,equal or larger?

My logic is that 3D airflow leakage on tips  will decrease overall pressure difference at wing ,so lift will be smaller than in 2D wing-test but drag will be also smaller than in 2D-test,because when you integrate smaller pressure difference over airfoil surface you will get smaller drag as well.

(**BUT** if we must have **SAME LIFT IN BOTH TEST**,than 3D wing test will have larger drag,because then we must increase AoA at 3D wing to compensate lift reduction caused by airflow leakage,so now  when we have increased AoA we also have larger drag..)

3D wing will have less drag,drag decrease when AoA decrease,3D wing "feel" effective AoA,so it fly at smaller "AoA" than 2D wing.

[image: 2D vs 3D]

[image]

how blue-lift can be larger than red-lift,wing at AoA=10 can not produce larger lift than wing at AoA=20 ??

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do wall-to-wall airfoils in wind tunnels produce no (or infinitesimal) downwash?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49346/why-do-wall-to-wall-airfoils-in-wind-tunnels-produce-no-or-infinitesimal-downw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

At relatively high Reynolds number (>1 million) and in attached flow, where the boundary layer is thin, 3D wing should always have larger overall drag than a 2D airfoil (infinite span), at the same free-stream incidence angle.

### Why?

The downwash generated from trailing vortices is actually very small compared to the free-stream airspeed; therefore, [the reduction in effective AOA](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/66300/41375) is also very small.

This results in three effects:

1. Reduction in lift due to tilting. This effect is exceedingly small, since cosine of a small angle is essentially unity.
2. Reduction in lift and pressure drag due to lower effective AOA. The reduction in lift is small but definitely non-negligible. For unseparated flow around an airfoil, the overall pressure drag is very small to begin with, so the reduction is even smaller.
3. Creation of induced drag due to tilting of the lift vector. This is the main one, since sine of a small angle produces non-negligible linear factor. For example, if the local lift coefficient, $C_l$, is 0.4, and we have an effective decrease in AOA of 1.0deg, then $C_l\cos{\frac{1.0\pi}{180}}\approx 0.9998C_l\approx0.4$, while the local induced drag coefficient, $C_{d_i}$, is $C_l\sin{\frac{1.0\pi}{180}}\approx0.0175C_l=0.007$.

By the way, the drag polar you cited doesn't help your argument since it's for the whole wing (at aspect ratio of 6). What you really want to cite is the airfoil drag (from [Airfoil Tools](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=clarky-il)):

[image: Clark-Y airfoil lift and drag]

As you can see, the form drag (includes pressure drag) is a small portion of the overall 3D drag at aspect ratio of 6, in the linear lift range. The pressure drag increase is even smaller.

### Addendum:

From your comments, it seems you have totally missed the point about induced drag. Induced drag is completely absent in 2D. In fact, if you assume that the flow is inviscid and without local supersonic flow, you have **zero** drag on any 2D airfoil. This is called [d'Alembert's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_paradox).

As mentioned above, induced drag appears in 3D inviscid flow due to finite span and induced downwash.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107567/discussion-on-answer-by-jzyl-will-3d-wing-has-smaller-drag-than-2d-at-same-aoa-a).

Comment: @JZYL This is only true when compare for the same lift,not for same AoA.JanHudec explain that here :https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80839/does-ducted-fan-require-more-engine-torque-than-unducted-fan-at-same-rpm

Comment: @Сократ, no this answer is absolutely correct. This compares a 2-D airfoil with a 3-D one, but in the linked answer we are comparing the same 3-D airfoil with and without end-plates, which makes a big difference.

Comment: @JanHudec What is difference in puting wall to wall 3D airfoil  in wind tunnel or 3D airfoil  in ductec fan? in both case you get 3D airfoil with infity big endplates What is definition of 2D airfoil?Just because he put  airfoil inside wind tunel from wall to wall ,that doesnt mean he has "theoretical" 2D airfoil with finite lift and infity span=zero induced drag? "theoretical"2D airfoil can not be simulate in real life

Comment: @Сократ a “2D” airfoil means infinite and for rather weird reasons that can produce even infinite lift with zero (not even just finite) induced drag. But it is a theoretical construct and that property comes out of the limits for increasing span. Endplates, no matter how big, will *not* make the wing behave as if it was infinite, only as if it was a little longer.

Comment: @JanHudec From original post 2D airfoil  description : `put airfoil in wind tunnel so walls touch arifoil tips(2D wing),at AoA=15degrees and airflow speed=20m/s and meassure lift and drag..`    Has his wall to wall airfoil zero induced drag ,like 2D airfoil?

Comment: @Сократ, hm, unless it is also very close to the bottom (in ground effect), it should have non-zero induced drag. The air is still being accelerated downward, so conservation of momentum requires the induced drag, and the surface is still tilted backwards and so is the pressure force.

Comment: @JanHudec `no this answer is absolutely correct.` Here is explanation why I think this answer is not correct..  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80919/wing-vs-wall-to-wall-wing-total-drag-comparation-at-same-aoa

Comment: @Сократ The question is on 2D vs 3D. It isn't (or isn't perceived to be) about wall-to-wall anything. What you're hung up on is just red herring.

Comment: @JZYL wing vector is tilted back but at same time magnitude is lower,so how  you can prove that this end up with increased drag,if you dont know how much magnitude is decrease?Peter also tell that this can not be prove..

Comment: @Сократ Then read the answer. #2 and #3 have this dealt with.

Comment: @JZYL in my example if reduction   of  aerodynamic  force is only 7% (65N) at wing,wing will has lower drag.alfa induced is ussualy very small 1degrees max ,so vector tilt back is  small

Comment: It looks to me like you're assuming the wing is in a wind tunnel (airflow constrained vertically). It looks to me like that may be a source of a lot of this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

3D wing has more drag as it considers vortices forming at the wing tip which creates more drag.But incase of 2D wing, the wing is assumed to be infinite wing. [Aerodynamically](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/aerodynamics/q0167.shtml), the effect of trailing vortices reduces the slope of the coefficient of lift vs. angle of attack curve. As a result,the coefficient of lift is higher in 2D wing than 3D wing for same AoA.
[image]